# Как дополнить скрипт?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

как дополнить скрипт табов, чтобы третья вложенность вкладок работала верно?
**Дано:** табы, помещенные друг в друга на JQuery
**Необходимо:** чтобы каждому родителю под цифрой "2" присваивался свой блок с контентом, а не брался общий к каждому первому родителю "2" во всех колонках

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.link').on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    const index = $(this).parent().children('.link').index($(this));

    let linksBlock = $(this).closest('.main-links');
    if (linksBlock.length === 0) {
      linksBlock = $(this);
    }

    linksBlock.siblings('.tab').hide();
    linksBlock.siblings('.tab').eq(index).show();
  });
});
```

```css
  .tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content>.tab>.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.tab {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
}

.model-first-row {
  display: flex;
}

.col-model {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.link {
  margin-right: 13px;
}

.hh1 {
  width: max-content;
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.model-first-row {
  background: orange;
  width: max-content;
  .txt-txt {
    background: wheat;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mama-tab">
  <div class='main-links'>
    <div class="sppb-nav sppb-nav-tabs tab-head-wrap hh1">
      <button id="sppb-content-1572967904513" class="link">1</button>
      <button id="sppb-content-1572967904514" class="link">1</button>
      <button id="sppb-content-1572967904515" class="link">1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <div class="mama-tab mama-2">
      <div class='main-links'>
        <div class="sppb-nav sppb-nav-tabs tab-head-wrap hd-sub">
          <div class="model-first-row">
            <div class="col-model col-model-01">
              <button class="link">2</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-model col-model-02">
              <button class="link">2</button>
              <button class="link">2</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-model col-model-03">
              <button class="link">2</button>
              <button class="link">2</button>
              <button class="link">2</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab">
        <div class='main-links'>
          <div class="txt-txt">
            Этот контент должен быть только у первой "2" в первой левой колонке, но его захватывает в               каждый первый "2" во всех колонках, причем второй и третий "2" в одной колонке (серединная  и правая) этот блок не захватывает
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ryzen помогите, пожалуйста, если у Вас есть время

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME призываю Вас!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.link').on('click', function() {
    $(this)
      .siblings('.tab')
      .toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="mama-tab">
  <div class='main-links'>
    <div class="sppb-nav sppb-nav-tabs tab-head-wrap hh1">
      <button id="sppb-content-1572967904513" class="link">1</button>
      <button id="sppb-content-1572967904514" class="link">1</button>
      <button id="sppb-content-1572967904515" class="link">1</button>
      <div class="tab">
        <div class="mama-tab mama-2">
          <div class='main-links'>
            <div class="sppb-nav sppb-nav-tabs tab-head-wrap hd-sub">
              <div class="model-first-row">
                <div class="col-model col-model-01">
                  <button class="link">1</button> 
                  <div class="tab">
                    <div class='main-links'>
                      <div class="txt-txt">
                        Этот контент должен быть только у первой "2" в первой левой колонке, но его захватывает в               каждый первый "2" во всех колонках, причем второй и третий "2" в одной колонке (серединная  и правая) этот блок не захватывает
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-model col-model-02">
                  <button class="link">2</button>
                  <button class="link">2</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-model col-model-03">
                  <button class="link">3</button>
                  <button class="link">3</button>
                  <button class="link">3</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
 
</div>
</div>

    <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```